# Backup Win 2008R2/2012 on rotating external disks

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-backup, windows-server-2012

I have 2 external drives. I would like to rotate the drives each week, so one week, I want to backup to Drive-A, next week to Drive-B and then next week back on Drive-A etc.

I see that Win 2008R2/2012 has an option called "Back up to a hard disk that is dedicated for backups", but I can't figure out how to add a second or third drive later - it seems like I have to attach all drives to the server, select the two (or more drives) when configuring the backup job, unplug so there's only one backup drive left and then I'm ready to backup. Only question is, how do I add a third drive later?

Thanks!

Mojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional drives after the fact by using `Wbadmin` from the command-line.

`Wbadmin ENABLE BACKUP -addtarget:{DiskID}`

The `AddTarget` parameter takes a disk ID as an argument, which can be retrieved by running `Wbadmin GET DISKS`.

- More info on WBAdmin [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754015%28WS.10%29.aspx).
- More info on using AddTarget to add drives [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverfiles/thread/f9cd6cf1-7846-4364-b0eb-1ac5999ffe6f).

Comment: Thanks! You know if using "Back up to a hard disk that is dedicated for backups" .. is just set and forget? Like do I have to erase disks or will Windows just delete old backups to make place for new backups? Thanks.

Comment: Backup is _never_ set and forget. :)  If the drives fill up (etc.) it will tell you (Event Logs), but you have to be watching for it.  You can setup email alerts for various results as well:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsbackup/thread/bcd72564-5763-4390-8626-bf3ecdea9d63, http://serverfault.com/questions/197883/sending-email-after-backup-windows-server-2008, http://serverfault.com/questions/122801/windows-server-2008-windows-server-backup-email-alerts

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :) ... Will Windows overwarite disks when it's full or will it log it and I'll have to reformat it every week? thx!

Comment: Nope, it should clean up after itself.  [Info here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2011/03/14/windows-server-backup-automatic-disk-usage-management.aspx)

Comment: thx for all your help :)